# Pandas pick an item from list column and search in other list column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'single_proj_name': [['jsfk'],['fhjk'],['ERRW'],['SJBAK']],
                          'single_item_list': [['ABC_123'],['DEF123'],['FAS324'],['HSJD123']],
                          'single_id':[[1234],[5678],[91011],[121314]],
                          'multi_proj_name':[['AAA','VVVV','SASD'],['QEWWQ','SFA','JKKK','fhjk'],['ERRW','TTTT'],['SJBAK','YYYY']],
                          'multi_item_list':[['XYZAV','ADS23','ABC_123'],['XYZAV','DEF123','ABC_123','SAJKF'],['QWER12','FAS324'],['JFAJKA','HSJD123']],
                          'multi_id':[[2167,2147,29481],[2313,57567,2321,7898],[1123,8775],[5237,43512]]})
```

I would like to do the below

a) Pick the value from `single_item_list` for each row

b) search that value in `multi_item_list` column of the same row

c) If match found, keep only that value in `multi_item_list` and remove all other non-matching values from `multi_item_list`

d) Based on the position of the match item, look for corresponding value in `multi_id` list and keep only that item. Remove all other position items from the list

So, I tried the below but it doesn't work

```
def func(df):
    return list(set(sample_df['single_item_list']) - set(sample_df['multi_item_list']))

sample_df['col3'] = sample_df.apply(func, axis = 1)
```

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the two lists in parallel (pandas 1.3+), and filter:

```
(sample_df
  .explode(['multi_item_list', 'multi_id'])
  .loc[lambda d: d['single_item_list'].str[0].eq(d['multi_item_list'])]
)
```

If you want your lists back:

```
(sample_df
  .explode(['multi_item_list', 'multi_id'])
  .loc[lambda d: d['single_item_list'].str[0].eq(d['multi_item_list'])]
  .assign(multi_item_list=lambda d: d['multi_item_list'].apply(lambda x: [x]),
          multi_id=lambda d: d['multi_id'].apply(lambda x: [x]),
         )
)
```

Output:

```
  single_proj_name single_item_list single_id           multi_proj_name multi_item_list multi_id
0           [jsfk]        [ABC_123]    [1234]         [AAA, VVVV, SASD]       [ABC_123]  [29481]
1           [fhjk]         [DEF123]    [5678]  [QEWWQ, SFA, JKKK, fhjk]        [DEF123]  [57567]
2           [ERRW]         [FAS324]   [91011]              [ERRW, TTTT]        [FAS324]   [8775]
3          [SJBAK]        [HSJD123]  [121314]             [SJBAK, YYYY]       [HSJD123]  [43512]
```

##### alternative using a list comprehension:

```
sample_df[['multi_item_list', 'multi_id']] = \
pd.DataFrame([next(([[x], [c[i]]] for i,x in enumerate(b) if x==a[0]), None)
              for a, b, c in
              zip(sample_df['single_item_list'],
                  sample_df['multi_item_list'],
                  sample_df['multi_id'])],
              columns=['multi_item_list', 'multi_id'])
```

Comment: For `Pandas > 1.3.0`: multi-column explode.

Comment: Can you try the alternative on your real dataset and let me know which one is the most efficient?

Comment: I get an error - `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: Then you don't always have lists of items I guess. Maybe NaNs? In which case you can first run a `dropna` on the DataFrame before applying it.

Comment: Sorry, I have list of lists. I updated my input now. But you can see the explode option doesn't work for this scenario. can help?

Comment: I get value error - `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (4, 2)` when I try list comprehension approach for my updated input data

Comment: Well, you're reaching the limits of pandas here, it's really not the appropriate tool to work with lists. I suggest that you restore the question to its original phrasing for clarity then. If need be open a new question to handle the specific other cases (maybe give it a try by yourself first).